# is it fine to use auto keyword in function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I know that meaning of `auto` keyword has been changed completely from C++11. But Recently I wrote a following simple program that compiles & runs fine when compiling with `=std=c++98` option.

```
#include <iostream>
void fun(auto int a)
{   
    a=3;
    std::cout<<a<<'\n';
}
int main()
{
    fun(3);
}
```

Orwell Dev C++ IDE gives me warning like following:

```
[Warning] 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
```

So, is it fine to use `auto` for function parameters or should I never use `auto` like this as in above program to maintain compatibility with C++11?

Comment: Another question is "Why would you ever use `auto` there, in any version of C++?" I can't think of a reason.

Comment: what does `auto int` should even mean?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is if you have code where you specifically need to issue an error in C++11 mode if one of the silent changes between C++98/C++03 and C++11 breaks the code. However, in that case, an `#if` condition with an `#error` if C++11 is used would be far better for readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until C++ 11 the `auto` keyword was a ["storage class specifier"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) whereas with C++ 11 it becomes a [type-induction specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto).

To answer your question: depending on the C++ standard you use to compile your code, adjust the use of the `auto` keyword accordingly. It's not portable across the pre/post C++ 11 boundary of the C++ standard.

Comment: Um, prior to C++11, `auto` as a storage class specifier.  But it was also a storage class specifier that meant nothing different than omitting it...

Answer (score 4):

> So, is it fine to use auto for function parameters or should I never use auto like this as in above program to maintain compatibility with C++11?

That depends on what you mean by "fine":

If you mean "will it compile?" then YES.

If you mean "is it a good practice", the answer is that it is not a practice at all; It was possible to do so and the code was perfectly valid (before C++11) but that time is passed, and I do not know of anyone who did this (not even for tricky interview questions).

In conclusion, **don't do it**.

Answer (score 0):

`auto` prior to C++11 was a storage class specifier, like `register` or `static` or `extern`.

It, however, was the default storage class specifier.  Valid C++03 code with it removed would have the same meaning, which is why C++11 felt comfortable stealing the keyword.

In short:

```
void fun1(auto int a) {   
  std::cout<<a<<'\n';
}
void fun2(int a) {   
  std::cout<<a<<'\n';
}
```

have the same meaning in C++03.  In C++11, `fun1` is ill-formed.

Simply remove it from all of your pre-C++11 codebases.  If the code was valid C++03, it will continue to have the same meaning.

There is a (very small) problem that some compilers might implement the K&R era C "by default, a type is `int`".  Ie, they might consider `auto x;` to mean `auto int x;`.  This was not valid C++03, however.  Compiling with sufficiently strict flags in C++03 mode should generate errors around that (ab)use of `auto`.

As an aside, C++11 also introduces a new storage class specifier, `thread_local`.  It steals `auto` for the use of auto-typed variables, and `auto` is no longer a storage class specifier.